# Installing drivers on HP B320i Controller Card?

Tags: vmware-vcenter, raid-controller, hp-proliant

In order to get vCenter to recognize the logical array that has been created, it looks like I need to update the Controller Card drivers. I think I have found them here

http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=5293148&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D0%257CswItem%253DMTX_16efb1385daf41ad8cd81e710b%257CswEnvOID%253D4115%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D3%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken

but am unsure of how to install them.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HP had an image to install vCenter that had the drivers embedded. Otherwise you need to follow the vCenter image builder instructions to embed the necessary drivers to recognize the harddrives.